# Call Terminal Command Simultaniously

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal, cron, sh

I have a .sh file with the following:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
        cd /path/to/cron/
        touch /var/crons/logs/Process1/`date +%Y%m%d`.log
        php -f Cron.php arg1 >> /path/to/log/`date +%Y%m%d`.log
        sleep 15
done
```

This checks for a new job every 15 seconds, and then runs the entire job. After finishing, it waits 15 seconds and checks again. If it finds one, it does the whole job without having any other processes running.

I don't want a formal cron every 5 seconds, because a job could take 10 minutes, and that would result in quite a few processes at once. However, I would like to have this file called three times within 15 seconds. My thoughts are to start the jobs 5 seconds apart, but if they end up being 1 second apart with 12 seconds wait, thats fine too.

Here is what I have in /etc/rc.local (to start it on server start up)

```
./path/to/cron/CronFile.sh
```

I tried putting the call more that once, but it never finishes the first call and thusly never moves to the second call. I tried using the `at` command to scheudle it for one minute in the future, but that didn't work either and three commands still result in one running.

How can I initially schedule the jobs to wait 15 seconds between each job, but have three separate processes running all on their own schedule?

Comment: just a note: if the "cd /path/to/cron" is mandatory, make it so : `cd /path/to/cron && { .... rest of the commands that needs it ... } || { ... message and exiting if it fails ... }` . Otherwise you can just get rid of it, apparently, here... maybe you just need to `php /path/to/cron/Cron.php arg1 >> /path/to/log/$(date +"%Y%m%d).log` ?  (the logfile's name could use also a "cron_" prefix...)

Comment: I agree. I wasn't sure of where I was going to put the files, so I did the cd separately. But I think I will just remove it all together.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question

> How can I initially schedule the jobs to wait 15 seconds between each job, but have three separate processes running all on their own schedule?

But not entirely as such, instead I provide a method for running at most, 3 jobs at once, and checking if a new job should start every 15 second (given that less than 3 jobs are running at the time of the check).

The way of doing this, is to have a variable ACTIVE_JOBS
Then have a function start_job.
In your while loop, every 15 seconds, you iterate over any new tasks, if there are any, you check if ACTIVE_JOBS -lt 3 and if it is, you start_job.

start_job increments ACTIVE_JOBS as the first thing, then calls php and decrements ACTIVE_JOBS before exiting.

Comment: Are you recommending I do a cron every 5 seconds, and then build the logic for throttling the events to three simultaneous jobs into the app? I initially considered that, but liked letting Ubuntu take care of the scheduling rather than my script. Its still a fairly new script, so being honest, I don't have all the errors worked out yet. I'd be afraid that the flag is set to 3 and then error out, making it always THINK its 3.